# Generate all possible combinations of strings of certain length in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, plsql

I have written a program to generate all possible combinations of strings of length two. The program is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE string_combinations
AS
  vblString1   VARCHAR2(100);
  vblString2   VARCHAR2(100);
  vblChr1      NUMBER;
  vblChr2      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  vblChr1 := 65;
  LOOP
    SELECT Chr(vblChr1) INTO vblString1 FROM dual;
    vblChr2 := 65;
    LOOP
      vblString2 := vblString1||Chr(vblChr2);
      Dbms_Output.put_line(vblString2);
      vblChr2:=vblChr2+1;
      EXIT WHEN vblChr2=91;
    END LOOP;
  vblChr1:=vblChr1+1;
  EXIT WHEN vblChr1=91;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I have used a loop inside another loop. So, if I have to generate strings of length three, I can simply use another loop. But that would be lengthy if I wish to generate strings of length 5,6,7 or more. How can I use recursion to achieve it?
I am using oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need **PL/SQL** to generate an alphabetical sequence. You could do it in pure **SQL** using **Row Generator** method.

```
WITH combinations AS
  (SELECT chr( ascii('A')+level-1 ) c FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 26
  )
SELECT * FROM combinations
UNION ALL
SELECT c1.c || c2.c FROM combinations c1, combinations c2
UNION ALL
SELECT c1.c
  || c2.c
  || c3.c
FROM combinations c1,
  combinations c2,
  combinations c3
/
```

The above would give you all possible combinations `c1`, `c2`, `c3` for single and two characters. For more combinations, you could just add combinations as `c4`, `c5` etc.

Comment: What a beautiful solution. Thanks for the quick reply. Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
SELECT * FROM a1;

       ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 a
         2 b
         3 c
         4 d
         5 e
```

5 rows selected.

```
SELECT a.id,b.name
  FROM (SELECT id FROM a1) a, (SELECT name FROM a1) b
 ORDER BY a.id, b.name;

       ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 a
         1 b
         1 c
         1 d
         1 e
         2 a
         2 b
         2 c
         2 d
         2 e
         3 a
         3 b
         3 c
         3 d
         3 e
         4 a
         4 b
         4 c
         4 d
         4 e
         5 a
         5 b
         5 c
         5 d
         5 e
```

25 rows selected.