# Generating all possible combinations of number set oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, combinations

In this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/33565783/9737797 thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989608/lalit-kumar-b Mr.Lalit Kumar B, give us all possible combinations. But another combinations I must be use to concate query command for other length. Is there possible, how can I set this combinations length dynamically? Thanks advance. Best regards.

Query is:

```
WITH combinations AS
   (SELECT chr( ascii('A')+level-1 ) c FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 26)
  SELECT * FROM combinations
    UNION ALL
  SELECT c1.c || c2.c FROM combinations c1, combinations c2
    UNION ALL SELECT c1.c || c2.c || c3.c FROM combinations c1, combinations c2, combinations c3;
```

Result (length two):  00 01 11 10

Other Combination result (length three): 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111

Comment: Do you need a parametrized query that acts like a table-valued function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood your need; if so, this could be a way:

```
with characters(c) as
(
     select chr( ascii('A') + level -1)
     from dual
     connect by level <= 2                      /* 2 instead of 26, just to try it */
)
select replace (sys_connect_by_path(c, ' '), ' ', '') as result
from characters
connect by level <= 3                           /* the length you need  */
order by level, result
```

For example, if I only use `A` and `B` (`level <=2` instead of `level <= 26`) and I want to get combinations up to 3 characters (`level <= 3`), I get:

```
A
B
AA
AB
BA
BB
AAA
AAB
ABA
ABB
BAA
BAB
BBA
BBB
```

Basically, this uses the recursion not only to generate the starting set of characters, but even to generate strings, with a parametric lenght obtained by the times (`level`) the query does a recursion over the characters set